# Shortening answer goes wrong?

Tags: ruby

I want to write a function to count the occurrences of all the letters in a str, sounded easy enough and I came up with this

```
def letter_count(str)

     hash = {}
     letters = str.gsub(' ','').split('')
     letters.each do |letter|
        if hash.include?(letter)
          hash[letter] += 1 
        else
          hash[letter] = 1
        end

     end
  hash

end

letter_count('moon') => {"m"=>1, "o"=>2, "n"=>1}
```

when I tried to shorten it to

```
def letter_count(str)

     hash = {}
     letters = str.gsub(' ','').split('')
     letters.each do |letter|
        hash[letter] += 1 if hash.include?(letter)
        hash[letter] = 1

     end
  hash

end
```

The answer became:

```
letter_count('moon') => {"m"=>1, "o"=>1, "n"=>1}
```

Can you please tell me what I went wrong??? Thank you!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line where you set `hash[letter] = 1` always executes. That is why your hash has each letter having a value of 1. You could use a ternary operator to get it to one line, like so:

```
letters.each do |letter|
    hash.include?(letter) ? hash[letter] += 1 : hash[letter] = 1
end
```

This is an if, else then statement. If the hash has the letter as a key then the value is incremented, else the hash stores the letter as a key and assigns '1' as its value.

A helpful link: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/ruby/examples-ruby-ternary-operator-true-false-syntax

Comment: Maybe it is not important, but this hash will return `nil` for a nonexistent letter. @Sergio's code would return `0`

Comment: You could also create the hash with a default value of `0` and then `hash[letter] += 1` without the explicit conditional.

Comment: Don't know whether this is idiomatic Ruby...but most other languages (and their users) frown on using `?:` for actions.  It's generally approved of solely for expressions; ie: you're generally expected to do something with the value, rather than just using the expression for its side effects.

Comment: Personally, I *always* frown on the `?:` conditional operator. In Ruby, `if`/`then`/`else` is already an expression (there are no statements in Ruby, only expressions), there's really no need to use the cryptic conditional operator: `if hash.include?(letter) then hash[letter] += 1 else hash[letter] = 1 end`.

Answer (score 4):

My personal implementation (just for fun):

```
str = "moon"
counts = Hash[ str.scan(/\S/).group_by(&:chr).map{ |c,a| [c,a.length] } ]
#=> {"m"=>1, "o"=>2, "n"=>1}
```

Comment: This is even more functional: `"moon".chars.group_by { |s| s }.each_with_object Hash.new do |(c, n), h| h[c] = n.size end`

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Not really; you are mutating the Hash during iteration, which is not _[functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)_.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
def letter_count(str)
  str.gsub(' ','').split('').each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |letter, hash|
    hash[letter] += 1
  end
end

letter_count('moon') # => {"m"=>1, "o"=>2, "n"=>1}
```

A little improvement: use `scan` instead of `gsub` + `split`

```
def letter_count(str)
  str.scan(/[^\s]/).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |letter, hash|
    hash[letter] += 1
  end
end

letter_count('sun and stars') # => {"s"=>3, "u"=>1, "n"=>2, "a"=>2, "d"=>1, "t"=>1, "r"=>1}
```

Answer (score 2):

This particular problem is a great example of how choosing the right algorithm, but even more importantly the right *data structure* can massively simplify the solution. In fact, in this particular case, choosing the right data structure will make the algorithm so trivial that it basically completely vanishes: the data structure already *is* the answer.

The data structure I am talking about is a `Multiset`: a `Multiset` is like a `Set`, except it doesn't store only unique items, instead an item can be added multiple times and the `MultiSet` will keep count of how often an item was added – which is exactly what you want. Basically, a `Set` tells you whether a particular item is in the `Set` *at all*, a `Multiset` in addition also tells you *how often* that particular item is in the `Multiset`.

Unfortunately, there is no `Multiset` implementation in the Ruby core library or standard library, but there [is a gem](https://RubyGems.Org/gems/multiset/).

The whole code is literally just:

```
def letter_count(str)
  Multiset[*str.chars]
end

letter_count('moon')
# => #<Multiset:#1 "m", #2 "o", #1 "n">
```

Yes, that's it. That's the entire code. As you can see, there is one occurrence of the letter `'m'`, two occurrences of the letter `'o'` and one occurrence of the letter `'n'`.

Comment: While that's elegant, I often prefer to stick with solutions that directly use the core language+libs for portability reasons.

Comment: "portability"? The gem is written in pure Ruby, so it seems like it'd be very portable. Are you saying you never use gems and, instead, prefer to reinvent the functionality others have already implemented?

Answer (score 1):

`hash[letter] = 1` will always execute. You can restructure your code like this:

```
letters.each do |letter|
    hash[letter] = 0 unless hash[letter]
    hash[letter] += 1
end
```

or without suffix conditionals:

```
letters.each do |letter|
    if hash[letter]
      hash[letter] += 1
    else
      hash[letter] = 1 
    end
end
```

Comment: I know something was wrong there but how to i put an 'else' in it? I want to shorten it as much as i can....is there anyway I can still keep the if statement and just insert the else?

Comment: @user2393426 No, suffix conditionals don't allow `else`.  If you want `if ... else ...` that's what you have to write.

Answer (score 0):

As already explained, the problem is because `hash[letter] = 1` is always executed.

To make your code even more short, you can completely get rid of the `if` by passing default value into your hash constructor:

```
hash = Hash.new(0)
letters.each { |letter| hash[letter] += 1 }
```